# Html.DropDownListFor different function for each value selected

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So in my ASP.NET MVC application I have a view with a dropdown list with multiple values. Basically I want to be able to call a different JS function for each selected value.

Model:

```
[Display(Name = "Rate")]
public string Rate { get; set; }
```

Here's my view:

```
List<SelectListItem> rate = new List<SelectListItem>();
    rate.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "1 Rate",
        Value = "1",

    });

    rate.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "2 Rates",
        Value = "2"
    });
    rate.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "3 Rates",
        Value = "3",
    });
    rate.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "4 Rates",
        Value = "4"
    });
    rate.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "5 Rates",
        Value = "5"
    });

}
    <div class="form-group">
          @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label text-left " })
    <div class="">

            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => rate,
                new SelectList(rate, "Text", "Value"),
                "Vælg rate",
                new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" })

    </div>
        </div>
```

I am not sure where exactly to add my js function. I tried stuff like adding "onchange" or "onclick" but they do not work.

Comment: Start by deleting the pointless `if` block. All your need is the 2nd one (the 4th parameter of `SelectList` constructor is ignoredwhen binding to a property. Just use `$('#Rate').change(function() { var rate = $(this).val(); .... });`

Comment: And why are you creating an identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from the first one - its just pointless extra overhead. It just needs to be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Rate, rate, "Vælg rate", new { ... })`

Comment: I edited the OP, is that what you meant?

Comment: Its `model => model.Rate, ....` And why `required = "required"` instead of applying the `[Required]` attribute and including `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Rate)` so you get client and server side validation

Comment: To answer the question (disregarding the MVC parts) - you can't have an 'onchange' element per `<option>` only on the `<select>`.  What you can do is have a handler that looks at the selected value and calls a corresponding handler.  That handler *can* be configured on the `<option>` itself (eg as a `data-*` property) (but you won't be able to configure it via `DropDownListFor`)

Comment: @freedomn-m could you please elaborate? I think I know what you mean but I don't know how to do it exactly

Comment: @StephenMuecke the .change doesnt seem to work ?

Comment: Have you included `jquery`? What errors are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: there is no error, but nothing happens. Its like it doesn't register that a ".change" happens. So I think I need to use something else? Or I did not add the id correctly? `
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Rate, rate,
                    "Vælg rate",
                    new { id="Rate", @class = "form-control", required = "required" })`

Comment: the ID appears correct when inspecting the element in Chrome

Comment: ok I found that in the browser I can get it through Rate.value ....

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.subitemid, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "Select Sub Category", new { @class = "form-control select2" })



     <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('select#subitemid').change(function () {
            var itemId = $(this).val();
});
});
</script>
```

i think it is useful for you

Comment: the .change doesn't seem to pick up on me selecting a new thing